# How to change maven repository folder in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, maven

In windows, maven downloads everything in the `C:\Documents And Settings\MyUser\.m2` folder (or `C:\Users\MyUser\.m2`). There exists some way to change the folder that it uses? Specially I want to set it to download anywhere BUT in the `Documents And Settings`/`Users` folder.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Look at your `settings.xml` in `${maven.home}/conf` or, preferrably, `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` (see [this](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#quick-overview) for details about the `settings.xml`). You can add (or uncomment) the following section:

```
  <!-- localRepository
  | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
  |
  | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  -->
 <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
```

as suggested by the commented out section already there by default. There, you should be able to change the path to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to figure out other things like setting the M2_HOME environment variable (it is not there by default). This should be set to the installation path where the bin folder is.

Comment: In case of doubt, on Windows it is fine with windows-style backslashes too, ie.   
<localRepository>E:\m2\repository</localRepository>

Answer (score 9):

**For Eclipse IDE**

If you are using your local maven as the Maven Installation in M2 plugin in Eclispe, editing the settings.xml wasn't enough for me. The plugin was still using the default {user.home}/.m2 as the repository location.

I had to go to : `Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings` and point to my local maven's settings.xml file in the Global Settings and/or User Settings input fields. Clicking apply will then start storing artifacts in the correct destination.

Comment: I guess you could extend this to any IDE that uses its own bundled Maven which in turn then has its own default settings. That way you end up with "cloned" repository easily taking gigabytes of extra wasted space.