# How to create a custom .m2 folder?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I have a default .m2 folder in the location {user.dir}/.m2. The problem is here the settings.xml is configured to add jar dependencies from organisation repository url. I want to create a different .m2 folder for my personal project, where it would store dependencies from maven global repository. How to do the same?

Comment: Have a look at the localRepository in the Maven settings file. You can provide a different location and indeed a different settings file with the `-s` parameter to Maven, which is what I do for temporary experiments to avoid filling ~/.m2 with garbage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change maven repository folder in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490135/how-to-change-maven-repository-folder-in-windows)

Comment: The easiest way to make a git repository in `$HOME/.m2` and commit the `settings.xml`  plus other configurations (you should of course ignore `repository` directory` and switch via a branch between two locations ... One of the `settings.xml` can configure the `localRepository` into a different directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change IDE setting (for IDEA) like that:

[image]