# Maven copying pom to an OneDrive location during build

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My java build is failing because for some reason Maven is trying to copy the POM file to an One Drive location. Earlier this was not the case. I just backed up my project to OneDrive.

This is causing the build to fail.

```
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ claims-admin ---
    [INFO] Installing C:\PAYG1\claims\pom.xml to C:\Users\C9001031\OneDrive - BRB Group Ltd\.m2\repository\au\com\aiaa\claims\claims-admin\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\claims-admin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] Failed to canonicalize path C:\Users\C9001031\OneDrive - BRB Group Ltd\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox-parent\2.0.6\pdfbox-parent-2.0.6.pom.lastUpdated: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid
[WARNING] Failed to canonicalize path C:\Users\C9001031\OneDrive - BRB Group Ltd\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox-parent\2.0.6\pdfbox-parent-2.0.6.pom.lastUpdated: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for resolution tracking file C:\Users\C9001031\OneDrive - BRB Group Ltd\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox-parent\2.0.6\pdfbox-parent-2.0.6.pom.lastUpdated
    [INFO]
```

There is no path defined in settings.xml

Any idea where I need to make changes to point to local directory instead of OneDrive?

Regard
R

Comment: Unrelated to this problem: PDFBox is at 2.0.26.

Comment: First you are using extreme old versions of plugins and also I would ask why do you se OneDrive and not a repository manager or the local cache? What is the problem?

Comment: maybe there are several settings.xml files? Or it has a relative path? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490285/535646

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me too. My eclipse workspace was ok, but i figured out that could change the user settings path on windows > Preferences > Maven > User settings.

Sometimes, the path is already filled, but is grayed. Retype the same path and after click on "Update Settings" button.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit gobal settings file maven-x.x.x\conf\settings.xml with
`<localRepository>C:\Users\XXX\.m2\repository</localRepository>`